# Detect Bottom sheet dialog fragment dismiss on base fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have `fragment` which contains `recycleview` with list. in `fragment` i'm calling another bottom sheet `dialog fragment`, i Want to know when i dismiss that bottom sheet `dialog fragment` how to refresh base fragments list.

I Have Tried `onpause` and `onresume` method in base fragment. Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method trigger when dialog fragment dismissed. To override the method in dialog fragment.

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    // use interface to callback method in base fragment
}
```

Comment: can you give me some example

Comment: https://androidwave.com/fragment-communication-using-interface/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I tried blow code and it worked.

```
 @Override
public void dismiss() {
    super.dismiss();
    ((MyActivity)context).myRefreshFunction();// 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> call BottomSheetDialogFragment
>
> on click event open buttomSheetDialgFragment

```
class GuestFragment : Fragment(){
        .
        .
        .
        .

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            binding.tvInfo.setOnClickListener {
                val dialogFragment = BottomSheetDogGiveReviewFragment(requireContext(),data.ratingData,data)
                // call back method
                dialogFragment.setOnBottomSheetDismissListener  {
                    resumeFragment()
                }
                dialogFragment.show(parentFragmentManager, "My  Fragment")
            }


        }

    }
```

> in BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
class BottomSheetDogGiveReviewFragment(context: Context) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
        //this is binding xml file
        private var _binding : FragmentBottomSheetDogGiveReviewBinding?=null
        private val binding get() = _binding!!
        
        //make this listener through call over Fragment mehod
        private var onDismissListener: (() -> Unit)? = null
        fun setOnBottomSheetDismissListener(listener: () -> Unit) {
            onDismissListener = listener
        }
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            _binding = FragmentBottomSheetDogGiveReviewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            val view = binding.root
            return view
        }
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


            //button click
            binding.tvSubmit.setOnClickListener {
                ....
                ..
                dialog!!.dismiss()
                onDismissListener?.invoke()
            }
        }

        //dialog them
        override fun getTheme(): Int {
            return  R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialog
        }
    }
```

> // buttom sheet dialog them
> //add the theme in your themes.xml file

```
//buttom sheet dialog style
        <style name="CustomBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
            <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheet</item>
        </style>
```